# I can't see the EditText variable value while debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

When i try to debug my project and put the breakpoint in an EditText variable the program stop and show me the variables when i try to see the value of EditText i see nothing however i put the same variable in the EditText "55"

```
Event = view.findViewById(R.id.event);
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if(Event.getText().toString().equals("55")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Please write first an event",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
```

this what show me in debug

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZG0o.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem i just change

```
public class CalendarDialogg extends DialogFragment{
```

to

```
public class CalendarDialogg extends AppCompatDialogFragment{
```

The problem was: the Class CalendarDialog can't access to the EditText so the result was always ("") when i change to AppCompat now the java class can access to layout interface